# Configuring odbc.ini file

Tags: odbc

I am Using open source odbc driver to connect my program.I have to use odbc.ini file,but the problem is it my driver is not able to read user defined options of my file.
 here is my queries.
1) can we modify the odbc.ini file.
2) what are the way we can read from odbc.ini

thanks in advance,
Vivek

Comment: It would really help if you specify what driver you are using. Yes you can modify your odbc.ini file. In fact you have to, to make sure that you specify the settings to make the connection to your database. But what those settings are depends on the driver you are using and the DBMS you are connecting to. There is also a odbcinst.ini file that can contain the settings for your driver. If you give more information you are more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are saying that the problem is the driver you are writing can't read the odbc.ini file. The official way to read the ini file is SQLGetPrivateProfileString().

When you say "can we modify the file", do you mean you don't have permission, or you dont know how to use vi?